# Calabash Android: how to repeat a scenario multiple times?

Tags: android, mobile, automation, android-testing, calabash

In `calabash-android`, how can I have a *Scenario* run multiple, specific times e.g. 50 times.

I understand I would have to create a custom `step definition` for this but how do I go about it?

Answer (score 2):

It is no clear to me, what you want to have changed during those 50 runs.
But a good way of doing this, that a former colleague of mine once showed me is this

```
Scenario Outline: I really need to run this a lot of times

    Given I have <Access> rights in feature <Feature>
    When I navigate to <Screen>
    Then the action <Action> is present

    Examples:
      | Screen         | Feature   | Access | Action              | Present |
      | Note           | Feature A | Create | Delete note         | Yes     |
      | Note           | Feature A | Create | Create note         | Yes     |
      | Note           | Feature A | Read   | Delete note         | No      |
      | Appointments   | Feature B | Create | Create appointment  | Yes     |
      | Appointments   | Feature B | Create | Delete appointment  | Yes     |
      | Appointments   | Feature B | Read   | Create appointment  | No      |
```

The idea here is that you write your scenario. Then you can execute that scenario with different values. Like doing different things on the screen etc. And just add one line to the table for each execution of the scenario.

In case this is to big a solution for you. You could use a loop

```
i = 0
while i < 50
   i += 1
   <do stuff>
end
```

Best regards
Lasse

Comment: It's worth noting that you can rename "Examples" to "Scenarios" (Gherkin parses it just fine), which might be more intuitive for a non-technical user to digest, since it's then understood that each row represents an individually run scenario.

Answer (score 1):

IF you have only one scenario that you wana run multiple times :
one approach :
1.Give some relevant tags to that scenario like @abc_50_times

2.Then go to  env.rb or hooks.rb in support (features/support/) , paste below code there

Around('@abc_50_times') do |scenario, block|
  500.times { block.call }
end

3.Once you done remove this tag(@abc_50_times) from the scenario , otherwise it will run 50 time every time .

other approach :

1. Give any tag to that scenario that you wana run multiple time (ex : @abc)

2.Write a shell script  : (ex: and save it within Features file as "multiple_run.sh" , Features/multiple_run.sh )
for (( i = 1; i <= 50; i++ ))
do

calabash-android run  --tags @abc

done

3.Give read and write permission 
chmod 777

4.Now run shell script :

> First navigate into Features : cd 
>   ./multiple_run.sh

This shell script make Scenario run multiple time ...